# Excel Vba - Copy/Link data to other sheet if meet the value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in the VBA. its there any way to connect with sheet 2 and sheet 1. See the picture below:

**Sheet 1**
[image: data in sheet1]

**Sheet 2**
[image: selected data in sheet2]

I tried using this VBA code but its not working.

```
Sub Finddata()  
Dim x As Long  
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate  
For x = 2 To    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count  
For y = 2 To 5  

On Error Resume Next  
Cells(x, y).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(x, "A").Value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:F18"), y = 1, 0)  
Next y  
Next x  

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Index and Match formulae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, this uses the .Find method to search for the given value in Sheet1 and then return by offsetting:

```
Sub Finddata()
Dim x As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim FindValues As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
'above declare variables

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Sheet2
For x = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last on Sheet2
    Set FindValues = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=ws2.Cells(x, 1).Value, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    'use the Find method to search for the value in Sheet1
    If Not FindValues Is Nothing Then 'if found
        ws2.Cells(x, 2).Value = FindValues.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(x, 3).Value = FindValues.Offset(0, 2).Value
        ws2.Cells(x, 4).Value = FindValues.Offset(0, 3).Value
        ws2.Cells(x, 5).Value = FindValues.Offset(0, 4).Value
        ws2.Cells(x, 6).Value = FindValues.Offset(0, 5).Value
        'pass the values into Sheet2
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier.wow! it's working perfectly! although I changed a little bit the declare variables. the rest of the code is working.  thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnuarMalik, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks